# (ERROR: Segmentation Fault) I'm new to pointers, so

Tags: c, runtime-error

I have this code, which I made myself using a pseudocode as a reference guide, but, upon saying to myself that I should not use global variables, I decided to learn about pointers. Specifically because I needed to return arrays (It can be done differently, but my logic works around arrays, and I really like them). So, after hours of coding and in-between testing, I got to this big and scary error: Segmentation Fault. That's what VSC tells me while debugging. Going forward on the execution of the code makes it crash. So, I would like if someone more experienced in pointers could help me a bit. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


unsigned long long int entrada(char arg);
unsigned long long int * procesado(unsigned long long int input);
void salida(unsigned long long int *data);

int main(){

    static unsigned long long int *out = 0;
    static unsigned long long int *sts = 0;

    printf("Ingrese cualquier letra para salir\n\r");

    while(!sts){
        out = procesado(entrada(0));
        *sts = out[2008];

    }
    salida(out);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int entrada(char arg){
    static unsigned long long int res;

    switch(arg){
        case 0:
            printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Ingrese el codidigo del producto: (max. 12 caract.)");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ingrese el valor del producto: $");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 3:
            printf("!!Ingrese una descripcion breve (max. 12 caract.): !! [NOT WORKING, INPUT ANY NUMBER]");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Ingrese el stock disponible: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad en gondolas disponible: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        default:
            if (arg == 'u'){
                printf("Saliendo...");
                return res;

            } else {
                printf("Ingrese una opcion correcta!\n\r");
            }
            break;
    }

}

unsigned long long int * procesado(unsigned long long int input){
    static int prodAlm, prodPan, prodFre, prodBaz, prodDes;
    static unsigned long long int prodAlmLiq[1000], prodBazLiq[1000];
    static int countAL, countBL;
    static int returnedValSlot, returning;
    static unsigned long long int out[2010];

    if (input == 'u'){ 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
            out[i] = prodAlmLiq[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
            out[i+1000] = prodBazLiq[i];
        }
        out[2001] = countAL;
        out[2002] = countBL;
        out[2003] = prodAlm;
        out[2004] = prodBaz;
        out[2005] = prodFre;
        out[2006] = prodPan;
        out[2007] = prodDes;
        out[2008] = 1;
        return out;

    }

    if (!returning){
        switch(input){
        case 10:
            prodPan++;
            break;
        case 20:
            prodAlm++;
            prodAlmLiq[countAL] = countAL+1;
            prodAlmLiq[countAL+2] = entrada(2);                                 //Pregunta por el precio del prod
            if(prodAlmLiq[countAL+2] >= 4.5 && prodAlmLiq[countAL+2] <= 5.5){
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+1] = entrada(1);                             //Pregunta codigo del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+3] = entrada(3);                             //Pide descripcion del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+4] = entrada(4);                             //Pregunta el stock disponible del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+5] = entrada(5);                             //Pregunta cantidad en gondola del prod
                countAL = countAL + 6;                                          //Da la vuelta a la estructura del arreglo para empezar una nueva linea
            }
            break;
        case 30:
            prodFre++;
            break;
        case 40:
        prodAlm++;
            prodBazLiq[countBL] = countBL+1;
            prodBazLiq[countBL+2] = entrada(2);                                 //Pregunta por el precio del prod
            if(prodBazLiq[countBL+2] >= 4.5 && prodBazLiq[countBL+2] <= 5.5){
                prodBazLiq[countBL+1] = entrada(1);                             //Pregunta codigo del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+3] = entrada(3);                             //Pide descripcion del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+4] = entrada(4);                             //Pregunta el stock disponible del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+5] = entrada(5);                             //Pregunta cantidad en gondola del prod
                countBL = countBL + 6;                                          //Da la vuelta a la estructura del arreglo para empezar una nueva linea
            }

        break;
        default:
        prodDes++;

        break;
    }
    printf("----------------------------------------\n\r           Producto Agregado!\n\r----------------------------------------");
    }
    
}

void salida(unsigned long long int *data){
    int prodAlm, prodPan, prodFre, prodBaz, prodDes;
    unsigned long long int prodAlmLiq[1000], prodBazLiq[1000];
    int countAL, countBL;

    //prodAlmLiq = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i >= 1000; i++){
        prodAlmLiq[i] = data[i];
    }
    //prodBazLiq = data[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i >= 1000; i++){
        prodBazLiq[i] = data[i+1000];
    }
    countAL = data[2001];
    countBL = data[2002];
    prodAlm = data[2003];
    prodBaz = data[2004];
    prodFre = data[2005];
    prodPan = data[2006];
    prodDes = data[2007];

    printf("Recuento de productos en los diferentes sectores:\n\r");
    printf("Hay %d productos de Panaderia\n\r", prodPan);
    printf("Hay %d productos de Almacen\n\r", prodAlm);
    printf("Hay %d productos Frescos\n\r", prodFre);
    printf("Hay %d productos de Bazar\n\r", prodBaz);
    printf("Hay %d productos desconocidos\n\r", prodDes);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n\r");
    printf("        RECUENTO PARA LIQUIDACION       \n\r");
    printf("----------------------------------------\n\r");
    printf("Nº  |Cod Rub    |Cod Prod       |Importe    |Descripcion            |Stock  |Gondola\n\r");
    for(int i = 0; i >= countAL; i++){
        printf("%d  |20         |%d             |%d         |%d                     |%d     |%d\n\r", prodAlmLiq[i], prodAlmLiq[i+1], prodAlmLiq[i+2], prodAlmLiq[i+3], prodAlmLiq[i+4], prodAlmLiq[i+5]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i >= countBL; i++){
        printf("%d  |40         |%d             |%d         |%d                     |%d     |%d\n\r", prodBazLiq[i], prodBazLiq[i+1], prodBazLiq[i+2], prodBazLiq[i+3], prodBazLiq[i+4], prodBazLiq[i+5]);
    }


}
```

As is, this code compiles with no errors or warnings, but something is wrong...

Since the error occurs on line 18, I tried switching the asterisk (*) around, but doing that made my code compile with the error/s:

```
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

for `sts = out[2008];`.

```
invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'long long unsigned int')
operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type "unsigned long long"
```

for `sts = *out[2008];`, and `*sts = *out[2008];`

Comment: There is an awful lot wrong here, not all of it pointer related. How many iterations do you expect this loop will have? `for(int i = 0; i >= 1000; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are dereferencing the NULL pointer sts in line 12 which is undefined behaviour.
2. If you want to use scanf or printf with an unsigned long long int you have to change the format specifiers from %d to %llu.
3. Your functions entrada and procesado have control flows which don't return anything. Add a default return value to the end of the function.
4. All the for loops in the function salida are infinite loops

Try compiling with -Wall -Werror and you will see lots of errors and warnings

Answer (score 1):

`sts` is 0 (a null pointer), it points nowhere, therefore you cannot dereference it. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is *undefined behaviour*, it usually results in a crash of your program.

```
int main(){

    static unsigned long long int *out = 0;
    static unsigned long long int *sts = 0;  // sts is 0 => it points nowhere

    printf("Ingrese cualquier letra para salir\n\r");

    while(!sts){
        out = procesado(entrada(0));
        *sts = out[2008];   // sts still points nowhere

    }
    salida(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Read again thge chapter dealing with pointers in your learning material and start with simpler exercises.

You won't learn anything by randomly putting and removing `*` in fron of variables.

I didn't check the rest of your code, but there are most likely similar problems.